# Database Errors since site updated to Wordpress 6.4.3

Tags: database, errors

I have stored my site in a cloud backup with localwp. Later I restored this backup into a new site. When I am inside the admin area I can see in the error log that errors are produced when accessing normal admin pages. The actual error is always: `WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list`

Accessing the "Media Library" screen:

```
[27-Feb-2024 11:22:21 UTC] WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'local.wp_posts.post_date' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT for query SELECT DISTINCT YEAR( post_date ) AS year, MONTH( post_date ) AS month
                FROM wp_posts
                WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
                ORDER BY post_date DESC made by wp_enqueue_media
[27-Feb-2024 11:22:21 UTC] WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'local.t.name' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT for query 
            SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id, tr.object_id
            FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (127, 124, 122, 64, 62)
            ORDER BY t.name ASC
            
         made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, _prime_post_caches, update_object_term_cache, wp_get_object_terms, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query, WP_Term_Query->get_terms
```

Accessing the "Posts" screen:

```
[27-Feb-2024 11:33:48 UTC] WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'local.t.name' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT for query 
            SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id, tr.object_id
            FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (127, 124, 122, 106, 70, 66, 64, 62)
            ORDER BY t.name ASC
            
         made by WP_Posts_List_Table->prepare_items, wp_edit_posts_query, wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, _prime_post_caches, update_object_term_cache, wp_get_object_terms, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query, WP_Term_Query->get_terms
[27-Feb-2024 11:33:48 UTC] WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'local.wp_posts.post_date' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT for query SELECT DISTINCT YEAR( post_date ) AS year, MONTH( post_date ) AS month
                    FROM wp_posts
                    WHERE post_type = 'post'
                    AND post_status != 'auto-draft' AND post_status != 'trash'
                    ORDER BY post_date DESC made by WP_List_Table->display, WP_List_Table->display_tablenav, WP_Posts_List_Table->extra_tablenav, WP_List_Table->months_dropdown
```

Accessing the "Dashboard" screen:

```
[27-Feb-2024 11:34:43 UTC] WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'local.t.name' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT for query 
            SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id, tr.object_id
            FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (127, 124, 122, 64, 62)
            ORDER BY t.name ASC
            
         made by wp_dashboard, do_meta_boxes, wp_dashboard_site_activity, wp_dashboard_recent_posts, WP_Query->__construct, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, _prime_post_caches, update_object_term_cache, wp_get_object_terms, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query, WP_Term_Query->get_terms
[27-Feb-2024 11:34:43 UTC] WordPress database error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'local.t.name' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT for query 
            SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id, tr.object_id
            FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (66, 70, 106)
            ORDER BY t.name ASC
            
         made by wp_dashboard, do_meta_boxes, wp_dashboard_quick_press, wp_dashboard_recent_drafts, get_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, _prime_post_caches, update_object_term_cache, wp_get_object_terms, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query, WP_Term_Query->get_terms
```

It doesn't seem to be affecting anything however. Everything still seems to be running and working.

To me it seems the queries generated by Wordpress are just wrong.

**What should I do with these errors?**

*edit: Corrected wrong version number in the title.*

Comment: Do you mean WordPress 6.x? WordPress 4.3.1 is 5 years old.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I meant to say Wordpress 6.4.3. I don't know how I switched up those numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors were generated because there was a plugin that forced sql modes to be used on the database that are actually "incompatible" with wordpress.

The following code was sadly executed for every request...

```
   private function set_sql_mode() : void
    {
        // Make sure no sql modes can be blocked (By wordpress built-in incompatible modes)
        add_filter('incompatible_sql_modes', fn() => [] );

        $this->DB->set_sql_mode([
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I haven't heard of that before. I guess it changed the way names with scopes are interpreted?

Comment: I will edit my answer! Thank you.